# Sufficient conditions that guarantee the integrate by part formula?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis, derivatives, sobolev-spaces

Suppose, for simplicity, that $f,g$ are functions defined on $[0,1]$. Under suitable hypotheses on $f$ and $g$, the integrate by parts formula yields
$$
\int_0^1 f'(t)g(t)dt = f(t)g(t)|_{t=0}^1 - \int_0^1 f(t)g'(t)dt\ .
$$
If $f$ and $g$ are assumed to be continuously differentiable then the formula holds, but this condition proves to be too strict in most cases. I know that absolutely continuous is a sufficient condition but is there any strictly weaker conditions that still give the same result?

More generally, what I really want to know is for $f,g$ that belong to a Sobolev space, says $H^k([0,1])$, is the formula
$$
\int_0^1 f(t)g^{(k)}(t)= \big[ \sum_{j=0}^{k-1}(-1)^jf^{(j)}(t)g^{(k-j-1)}(t)|_{t=0}^1\big] + (-1)^k\int_0^1f^{(k)}(t)g(t)dt
$$
always justified and why?

I don't have any good book about Sobolev space at hand. I would really appreciate if someone could suggest me a good book on the subject.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following result tells that $u \in H^1$ is not less restrictive than absolutely continuous.

> **Theorem:** Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}$ be an open set, let $1\le p < \infty$. Then $u \in W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ if and only if it admits an absolutely continuous representative whose classical derivative belongs to $L^p(\Omega)$.

A proof of this theorem can be found, for example, in *Sobolev Spaces* by G. Leoni.

Comment: Thank you for your respond. I have heard about the theorem before and don't seem to know how to apply it to the case $k>1$. Is there an analog of that for $W^{k,p}$ where $k>1$? By the way, could you please elaborate on how to justify the iterated formula for integrate by parts? Do we simply repeatedly apply your theorem $m$ times?

Comment: You just need to iterate: if $u \in H^2$ then $\partial_iu \in H^1$ and hence it is absolutely continuous with integrable derivative. The formula can be proved by induction on $k$, each step being justified by the iterated application of the theorem I quoted.

Comment: Thanks a lot! 1 more thing, is the book you mentioned an introductory level textbook? I have just recently became interested in theory of Sobolev space and Distribution.

Comment: You are welcome! I might be biased since the author is my advisor, but I would say that it is a very good introduction/reference to the subject. If you are self-learning the material you might want to ask someone for an advice on what to skip at first read. :)

Comment: Another text that I often see recommended is Adams' Sobolev Spaces. I can't say much about this one since I am not familiar with it.